# Having two RSS Feed URLs for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am using MailChimp for my self hosted WordPress blog. MailChimp fetches RSS feeds for it's email templates. I want to add small thumbnail with excerpts in RSS feed so that they appear on MailChimp's email template but I do not want to modify the original RSS feed URL. I want to have a different URL for feeds modified for MailChimp like this: mysite.com/mailchimpfeed where as the original mysite.com/feed remains unchanged.

What will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basic MailChimp feed:

Here's one simple idea:

```
/**
 * Basic MailChimp feed 
 *
 * Example: domain.com/mailchimpfeed
 */

function mailchimp_feed()
{
    add_feed( 'mailchimpfeed', 'do_feed_rss2' );
}
add_action('init', 'mailchimp_feed' );
```

to reuse the native RSS2 feed, under a different url.

### MailChimp feed with featured images:

If we want to add the featured images to the MailChimp feed, we can use:

```
/**
 * MailChimp feed with featured images
 *
 * Example: domain.com/mailchimpfeed
 */

add_action('init', 'mailchimp_feed' );

function mailchimp_feed()
{
    add_feed( 'mailchimpfeed', 'mailchimp_feed_template' );
}

function mailchimp_feed_template()
{
    add_action( 'rss2_item', 'mailchimp_media_item' );
    add_action( 'rss2_ns',   'mailchimp_ns' );
    do_feed_rss2();
}

function mailchimp_ns()
{
    print 'xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss"';
}

function mailchimp_media_item()
{
    if( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) )
        $image = array_shift( wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large' ) ) ); 
    else
        $image = sprintf( '%s/default.jpg', get_site_url() );

    printf( '<media:content url="%s/default.jpg" medium="image" />', $image );
}
```

We can then modify the featured image size to our needs and the default image if there's no one set.

### Flush rewrite rules once to activate:

In both cases we just have to remember to flush the permalinks settings to activate the custom MailChimp feed.

--
Hope this helps.